# is it possible to join sub document with document with specific fields on MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is user collection(pseudo):

```
[
    {
        _id: ...,
        email: 'user1@exam.com'
        image: 'user1.png',
        nickname: 'appleGuy',
        createdAt: ...,
        updatedAt: ...
    },
    {
        id: ...,
        email: 'user2@exam.com',
        image: 'user2.png',
        nickname: 'bananaGuy',
        createdAt: ...,
        updatedAt: ...
    }
]
```

You can see the fields: email, image, nickname. And this is other collection for implement addressbook:

```
[
    {
        _id: ...,
        email: 'user1@exam.com',
        list: [
            {
                email: 'user2@exam.com',
                createdAt: ...,
                updatedAt: ...
            },
            {
                email: 'user3@exam.com',
                createdAt: ...,
                updatedAt: ...
            }
            { ... },
            { ... }
        ]
    }
]
```

Each document of addressbook has email field to distinguish whose addressbook it is, and list field to contain each item.
as you can see, addressbook.list is array, so it can call as sub document.
But sub document doesn't contain nickname and image field so I want to join them.
I think I can do this with aggregation pipeline. I can do this with normal documents but I don't know how do this with document on sub document. Also document of user collection and addressbook.list, both have createdAt and updatedAt field(same name, different data), and I want to project in addressbook.list. How should I do? Any advice will very appreciate.

Comment: Can you show your expected result structure?

Comment: thanks, titi23. i solved with $unwind and $lookup, $project!

Comment: if you solved this - please post your solution to enlight others or delete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved!

```
db.addressbook.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { email }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$list'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            email: '$list.email'
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'user',           
            localField: 'email',    
            foreignField: 'email',  
            as: 'embedded'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$embedded'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            email: '$email',
            nickname: '$embedded.nickname',
            image: '$embedded.image'
        }
    }
]);
```

result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "email" : "user2@exam.com",
    "nickname" : "user2",
    "image" : "default"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "email" : "user3@exam.com",
    "nickname" : "user3",
    "image" : "default"
}
```